# Websites do not load occasionally

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, wifi, mojave

I've bought a new macbook air 17 several months ago and often it stops to load websites. It can happen at any moment on any website: loading line freezes somewhere at the beginning. (Waiting doesn't help)

To disconnect and immediately connect to wi-fi helps, but after some clicks it happens again so I can connect and disconnect 10+ times in a row, loading one or two links in a time.

I'm using Safari but when I've tried to use Google chrome nothing has changed (they stop loading at the same time). I've never noticed this problem with discord or skype. It happens regardless of which wi-fi I use. How to fix it?

My OS is Mojave 10.14, safari version is updated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  There's no such machine as Macbook Air 17, can you please double-check the device?  Is this issue just for web sites or does it happen for everything you connect via wifi?  Do you connect other devices to the same wifi?  If so, does this happen to those devices, too?

Comment: When the problem is happen run WiFi diagnostics. Hold Option and click the WiFi icon on the Menu bar; select “Diagnostics.”  Run it and save the report. Post your results.  You may want to practice a bit first so you’re ready when the disconnect happens.

Comment: @fsb I mean macbook air 2017. I've never faced this problem while using something other than internet browsers, I think it's for web sites only. Other devices work fine with this wifi

Comment: I've made diagnostics. There is a folder with many files. Which one do I need to post?

Comment: Can you list the files?